# Downloading Videos from YouTube - Terms & Conditions

Tags: youtube-api

I am a bit confused about the YouTube API's term & conditions. If I create an app for users to  **download only their own videos**. Is that against the terms and conditions?

I know downloading other people content is definitely prohibited, but is it the same for your own videos? Since user can go to their video manager and download their own videosm this would be only a short-cut?

Anyone knows can/cannot do this? I was thinking of using this library http://ytdownloadextension.codeplex.com/

Any guidance would be appreciated,

Covo

Answer (score 10):

Seems like YouTube already allows you to do that, so I'd say it's legal:

> **Download your videos**
>
> You can’t download other people’s YouTube videos, but ...
>
> You can download MP4 files of videos that you’ve uploaded to YouTube in either 720p or 360p, depending on the video size.

See [Download videos that you've uploaded](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56100).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so the [Terms of Service of Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms) or the [Terms of Service of the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=en) allows you to do so:

#### Excerpt of Youtube ToS `(5. K)`:

> you agree not to access Content or any reason other than your personal, non-commercial use solely as intended through and permitted by the normal functionality of the Service, and solely for Streaming. "Streaming" means a contemporaneous digital transmission of the material by YouTube via the Internet to a user operated Internet enabled device in such a manner that the data is intended for real-time viewing and not intended to be downloaded (either permanently or temporarily), copied, stored, or redistributed by the user.

#### Excerpt of the API ToS `(II. 11)`:

> store copies of YouTube audiovisual content;

Both, state in a very clear way that neither the user nor applications built using the API can "store" content, which is a very direct statement that disallows you from giving such an option in your app. Now, whether Youtube does give its users an interface to download their content or not is an argument out of sequence here as Youtube don't need to follow their own ToS, in other words, it's up to them to give their users such an option, but you can't give it to the users of your app.

I suppose you need a special permission from Youtube to give such an option in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can definitely download your own videos from YouTube as it is your own content so you have full rights to it as the creator of the videos.