# Download/Find and Stream Youtube video using Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: video, download, youtube, google-chrome-devtools, media

I want to download/extract videos from youtube using Google Chrome Dev Tools. When I inspect the element, I see this in Dev Tools:

```
<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" style="width: 1004px; height: 753px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/db4f4abe-c290-4e61-a904-68435fdd9933"></video>
```

I've tried going to Network -> searching for .mp4 and .flv but nothing is showing.

How can I download using Dev Tools? Also, is there a way to get the video link and have nothing but the video play in a new tab?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That blob URL is virtual. It's produced by MediaSource API so it's not usable elsewhere. You'll need to get the original video/audio chunks and feed them into a compatible js player library. There might be solutions for that already. Otherwise you'll have to reverse-engineer the youtube's approach yourself.

Comment: Any way to get the original chunks? Can I do something with the Youtube API (although I am not familiar with APIs too much)?

Comment: I was trying to say you can use devtools - its network panel specifically - to investigate it. That is in case there are no existing solutions.

Comment: I tried looking there, no luck. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "no luck". Here's what I see https://puu.sh/Czsnu/c5fdd674a8.png so the next step is to investigate the code and see how these URLs are generated and used.

Comment: Sorry, I actually closed the window for that Youtube video in my question so I don't have URL to that specific video anymore as I don't remember what video it was. Where would the URLs in the Network tab be generated besides the Network tab?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? do you just want to download videos for offline use then you can already download your own from the dashboard (note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466739/downloading-videos-from-youtube-terms-conditions)

Comment: I wanted to see if it was possible using only Chrome Dev Tools to find the video link and either be able to download the video, or stream the video in another tab with only the video playing (like a webpage with a black background, but only the video is playing).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes **it is possible** (maybe not legal) but I want to explain the technical part (note that I don't download videos from YouTube, there is no reason, as it is always there on the cloud!).

YouTube transmits those streams in bytearrays and if you check for one clear url it doesn't exist.
BUT: if you look in the dev tools and trace the network you can find this url.

Take a look at this image:
[image]

YouTube transmits in separate channels and at runtime puts it all together,
using XMLHttpRequest to get the video and audio separately.

All calls which start with `videoplayback?` are about the video/audio streaming.
The `videoplayback?` Ajax calls always come paired together: `content-type= audio/*` and `content-type= video/*` in some order.

You can individuate them from the headers (in the image it looks like `content-type= video/*` or `content-type= audio/*`)

To GET FULL AUDIO/VIDEO STREAM THE ONLY THING TO DO IS :
Change the parameter `RANGE`.

The parameter `RANGE` specifies the segment of this content to stream (which is never normally the entire media since then it wouldn't be streaming, and to avoid downloads from nerd people)

Copy the url which starts with `videoplayback?` (like is shown in the image).
Find the parameter `range=` at the end of the querystring. The parameter `range=` is composed of a START and END (eg. range=18096-20098) which are separated by a “-”.

Put 0 (zero) for START and a long number for END like 9999999999 (eg. `range=0-999999999999`). *(Editor note, my guess is that these are the 'seconds' timestamps of the video)*

After you have modified this URL, copy and paste it in a new tab in your browser and you can simply download the audio or video.

Get both streams and put them together in some audio/video editing software (eg. NUENDO)

IMPORTANT: Don't change other parameters, as this is a self validating URL.

Comment: Hi @dantechguy editor. Thanks for providing and editing to my answer in a better English. Not your note is not about time is length of bytes that file have. Stay safe ;) Gent

Comment: Then how does download managers and other websites get to generate official google links with audio AND video combined?

Comment: Open a new question in SO explaining your doubts (as above) then, I’m sure, there is (maybe) an answer for you. The answer above is related to OP question.